# How do I use promises and loops together without promise.defer?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I'm fairly new to promises, and I'm having a problem avoiding some of the things I see described as promise anti-patterns (like Q.defer()).  I have a loop that is mostly synchronous, but may occasionally need to make an asynchronous call. The code was very simple before I added the asynchronous calls, but the changes I had to make in order to keep it working with asynchronous calls is very messy.

I would like some advice on how to refactor my code.  The code is trying to take selected properties of one object and add them to another. A simplified version is as follows:

```
function messyFunction(user, fieldArray) {
    return Promise.fcall(() => {
        var deferred = Promise.defer();

        if (!fieldArray) {
            deferred.resolve(user);
        } else {
            var temp = {};
            var fieldsMapped = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++) {
                var field = fieldArray[i];
                if (field === 'specialValue') {
                    doSomethingAsync().then((result) => {
                        temp.specialField = result;
                        fieldsMapped++;
                        if (fieldsMapped === fieldArray.length) {
                            deferred.resolve(temp);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    temp[field] = user[field];
                    fieldsMapped++;
                    if (fieldsMapped === fieldArray.length) {
                        deferred.resolve(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    });
}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `Q.all`.

Comment: What's with the `fcall` wrapper?

Comment: Yeah the fcall is probably unnecessary.  Can you post an example with Q.all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would refactor it. I'm not super familiar with `q`, so I just used native Promises, but the principal should be the same.

To hopefully make things more clear, I've de-generalized your code a bit to turn `messyFunction` into `getUserFields`, asynchronously calculating the age.

Instead of using a `for` loop and using a counter to keep track of how many fields have been collected, I put them in an array and then pass it into [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Once all of the values for the fields are collected, the `then` on the `Promise.all` promise resolves to the new object.

```js
// obviously an age can be calculated synchronously, this is just an example
// of a function that might be asynchronous.
let getAge = (user) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve((new Date()).getFullYear() - user.birthYear);
    }, 100);
  });
};

function getUserFields(user, fieldArray) {
  if (!fieldArray) {
    // no field filtering/generating, just return the object as
    // a resolved promise.
    return Promise.resolve(user);
    // Note: If you want to make sure this is copy of the data,
    // not just a reference to the original object you could instead
    // use Object.assign to return it:
    //
    // return Promise.resolve(Object.assign({}, user));
  } else {
    // Each time we grab a field, we are either store it in the array right away
    // if it is synchronous, if it is asyncronous, create a thenable representing
    // its eventual value and store that.
    // This array will hold them so we can later pass them into Promise.all
    let fieldData = [];

    // loop over all the fields we want to collect
    fieldArray.forEach(fieldName => {
     // our special 'age' field doesn't exist on the object but can
     // be generated using the .birthYear
     if (fieldName === 'age') {
        // getAge returns a promise, we attach a then to it and store
        // that then in fieldData array
        let ageThenable = getAge(user).then((result) => {
          // returning a value inside of then will resolve this
          // then to that value
          return [fieldName, result];
        });
        
        // add our thenable to the promise array
        fieldData.push(ageThenable);
      } else {
        // if we don't need to do anything asyncronous, just add the field info
        // to the array
        fieldData.push([fieldName, user[fieldName]]);;
      }
    });
    
    // Promise.all will wait until all of the thenables to be resolved before
    // firing it's then. This means if none of the fields we were looking for
    // is asyncronous, it will fire right away. If some of them were
    // asyncronous, it will wait until they all return a value before firing.
    // We are returning the then, which will transform the collected data into
    // an object.
    return Promise.all(fieldData).then(fields => {
      // fields is an array of 2-element arrays containing the field name
      // and field value for each field we are collecting. We will loop over
      // this array with reduce and transform them into an object containing
      // all of the properties we collected.
      let newUserObj = fields.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { 
        acc[key] = value;
        return acc;
      }, {});
      // Above I am using destructuring to get the key/value if the browsers
      // you are targeting don't support destructuring, you can instead just
      // give it a name as an array and then get the key/value from that array:
      //
      // let newUserObj = fields.reduce((acc, fieldData) => { 
      //   let key = fieldData[0],
      //     value = fieldData[1];
      //   acc[key] = value;
      //   return acc;
      // }, {});
      
      // return new object we created to resolve the then we returned
      return newUserObj;
    });
  }
}


let users = [
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    birthYear: 1986
  },
  {
    name: 'Dick',
    birthYear: 1976
  },
  {
    name: 'Harry',
    birthYear: 1997
  }
];

// generate a new user object with an age field
getUserFields(users[0], ['name', 'birthYear', 'age']).then(user => {
 console.dir(user);
});

// generate a new user object with just the name
getUserFields(users[1], ['name']).then(user => {
 console.dir(user);
});

// just get the user info with no filtering or generated properties
getUserFields(users[2]).then(user => {
 console.dir(user);
});
```

Comment: I simplified the code a bit. After thinking about it, I realized you don't need the extra Promise wrapped around the code, you can just return the `.then` attached to the `Promise.all` promise.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This looks much better than what I have.